# Are questions about seeking asylum allowed?

Tags: discussion

I'm tempted to ask a question on how to seek asylum, given the whistleblower in the news and talk of how he might try for it.

I'm questionable as to whether it's travel related or immigration. Thoughts?

Comment: for me it's definitely immigration

Comment: It might be on-topic on [Politics.SE].

Comment: @gerrit interesting, that's new! I predict flame wars ;)

Answer (score 10):

I think it's not very different from immigration, and as such should be off-topic for Travel-SE.

That being said, if there's a significant travel element, it could be allowed, but if the essence of the question is "How to seek asylum in country X", it's probably going to be closed.

Comment: Yeah.  A question on say, how he could get from Hong Kong to Iceland in order to get asylum would be travel, but the actual asylum process, probably not?

Comment: @MarkMayo: We never really cared *why* one travels from A to B (and why should we?), so the reasons are only to provide some context if needed. The process of applying for asylum and related issues should be off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Questions about asylum, how to get it, what the chances of getting it, and so forth are uniformly off-topic. A claimant wants to change where they live, they do not come for a holiday.

Moreover, who knows the asylum rules? Not me. Anybody?  Our little corner of specialty is UK Appendix V and the Schengen Borders Code.

**Proposed: Mark as off-topic and flag for moderator attention. Moderators migrate to Expats or delete altogether**

The very last thing we want is to have a high search ranking for asylum, trust me on that one.